# Acces array in deep nested child component

Tags: angular, ionic3

I was wondering how to acces a childscomponent array, the structure looks like this:

`parent.component.ts -> child.component.ts -> child.component2.ts`

In child.component2.ts there I have an array which I would like to acces in main.component. Is this possible by setting an template variable or do I need to work with an `Output()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more way to solve it is to create service which will contain array variable and then inject it to main.component.ts and child.component.ts

custom.service.ts

```
@Injectable() 
export class CustomService {
 myArray = [1,2,3,4];
}
```

main.component.ts

```
export class MainComponent {
  constructor(private customService: CustomService) {}
  myArr = this.customService.myArray;
}
```

child2.component.ts

```
export class MainComponent {
  constructor(private customService: CustomService) {}
  myArr = this.customService.myArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the child component2 in main component constructor method.

**child.component2.ts**

```
getUniqueArray(){
  return [1,2,3,4,5];
}
```

**main.component.ts**

```
constructor(private child2: ChildComponent2){
   this.child2.getUniqueArray();
}
```